# How use LibraryFunctionDeclaration to call the function with DataStore parameter?

Tags: data-types, function-compile

I have a `CMakeProject1.dll` produced by this code:

```
#include"LLU/LLU.h"

EXTERN_C DLLEXPORT int ReverseStrings1(WolframLibraryData libData, mint Argc, MArgument* Args, MArgument Res){
    LLU::MArgumentManager mngr{ libData, Argc, Args, Res };
    auto dsIn = mngr.get<LLU::GenericDataList>(0);
    LLU::GenericDataList dsOut;
    for (auto node : dsIn) {
        std::string_view s = node.as<LLU::NodeType::UTF8String>();
        std::string reversed{ s.rbegin(), s.rend() };
        dsOut.push_back(std::string_view(reversed));
    }
    mngr.set(dsOut);
    return LLU::ErrorCode::NoError;
}

EXTERN_C DLLEXPORT LLU::GenericDataList ReverseStrings2(LLU::GenericDataList dsIn) {
    LLU::GenericDataList dsOut;
    for (auto node : dsIn) {
        std::string_view s = node.as<LLU::NodeType::UTF8String>();
        std::string reversed{ s.rbegin(), s.rend() };
        dsOut.push_back(std::string_view(reversed));
    }
    return dsOut;
}
```

Of course we can call the `ReverseStrings1` by `LibraryFunctionLoad` like:

```
dll = "D:/test/CMakeProject1/build/Release/CMakeProject1.dll";
fc = LibraryFunctionLoad[dll, "ReverseStrings1", {"DataStore"}, "DataStore"]
fc[Developer`DataStore["abc", "Teacher", "List"]]
```

> Developer`DataStore["cba", "rehcaeT", "tsiL"]

But is possible use `LibraryFunctionDeclaration` + `FunctionCompile` to call `ReverseStrings2`? I mean how to set the "type?" in following code:

```
dec = LibraryFunctionDeclaration[fun->"ReverseStrings2",dll, {"type?"}->"type?"];
fc = FunctionCompile[dec, Function[Typed[lis, "type?"], fun[lis]]]
```

Do we need to define a new type with `CreateDataStructure`? If we do need this, how do we implement it?